# XRDP on Ubuntu can't work

Tags: server, xfce, remote-desktop

I'm just trying to apply XRDP to Ubuntu. Before I was applying XRDP to Kali and it works. But when I tried to apply it on Ubuntu it doesn't.

Must I change the session when I connect to the remote desktop?

This was the output service when I tried to start XRDP:

```
Starting Remote Desktop Protocol server                                                                      
[20201013-03:48:00] [DEBUG] Testing if xrdp can listen on 0.0.0.0 port 3389.
[20201013-03:48:00] [ERROR] g_tcp_bind(6, 3389) failed bind IPv6 (errno=98) and IPv4 (errno=22).
[20201013-03:48:01] [DEBUG] Closed socket 6 (AF_INET6 :: port 0)
[20201013-03:48:01] [ERROR] Failed to start xrdp daemon, possibly address already in use.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read the error messages! They clearly indicate that an XRDP instance is already running, and has grabbed the TCP port that is a requirement.

You must find, and shutdown that XRDP instance.

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:3389
```

will find it.

Read `man lsof kill pkill xrdp`.